# Android,Custom ListView not showing off correctly the Text

Tags: android

I have a custom LisView, in this ListView for each line I have a TextView and Imageview

how could i make each line of my ListView Higher ??

Thanks for Helping!!!

Comment: You should post your ListView and list item layout XMLs.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of class ViewHolder

```
private class ViewHolder {
        TextView title1;
        ImageView image1;
    }
```

This in getView() method:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(yourLayoutFile, parent, false);
```

By using this class and your custom xml file, you will be able to make your line of listview higher